# Gwenview on Ubuntu keep crashing when I start viewing it on fullscreen or playing slideshow

Tags: 14.04

I'm currently using Ubuntu Unity 14.04 Trusty Tahr. Are there any better alternatives for  gwenview?

Answer (score 0):

`Gwenview` is a KDE application. Although unlikely it maybe crashing because its expecting to be used on the KDE desktop. You can file a bug [here](https://bugs.kde.org/buglist.cgi?bug_file_loc_type=allwordssubstr&bugidtype=include&chfieldto=Now&cmdtype=doit&long_desc_type=allwordssubstr&product=gwenview&short_desc_type=allwordssubstr)

## [shotwell](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/shotwell) [image: Install shotwell]

`Shotwell` is a great photo manager and comes standard in the Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop install.

Comment: shotwell cannot show GIF files or videos.